# Post image to API gateway

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services

I want to be able to upload images to S3 via my API Gateway using React JS. I pasted the code snippet nodejs from postman, and it seems to work. After watching several different tutorials, I have been unable to do this through my React Frontend.
**NODEJS Version**

```
const axios = require('axios');
const FormData = require('form-data');
const fs = require('fs-extra');
let data = new FormData();
data.append('filename', fs.createReadStream('/Users/hp/Downloads/IMG_0733.jpg'));

let config = {
  method: 'put',
  url: 'htetps://XXXXX.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/XXXXX/IMG_0733.jpg',
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg', 
    ...data.getHeaders()
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then((response) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Above works, but I hard-coded the file, I want to upload the image file directly from the frontend. I used code I got from geeks for geeks and tried to replicate, however it does not work. Any suggestions would really be appreciated.

**REACT JS **

```
import axios from 'axios';
  
import React,{Component} from 'react';
  
class Upload extends Component {
   
    state = {
  
     selectedFile: null
    };
     
   onFileChange = event => {
     
     this.setState({ selectedFile: event.target.files[0] });
     
    };
     
   onFileUpload = () => {
     
      var myHeaders = new Headers();
      myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
      
      var file = "<file contents here>";
      
      var requestOptions = {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: file,
        redirect: 'manual'
      };
      
      fetch("https://XXX.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/XXXX/IMG_0733.jpg", requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
     
      // Request made to the backend api
      // Send formData object
    };
     
    // File content to be displayed after
    // file upload is complete
    fileData = () => {
     
      if (this.state.selectedFile) {
          
        return (
          <div>
            <h2>File Details:</h2>
            <p>File Name: {this.state.selectedFile.name}</p>
  
            <p>File Type: {this.state.selectedFile.type}</p>
  
            <p>
              Last Modified:{" "}
              {this.state.selectedFile.lastModifiedDate.toDateString()}
            </p>
  
          </div>
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <div>
            <br />
            <h4>Choose before Pressing the Upload button</h4>
          </div>
        );
      }
    };
     
    render() {
     
      return (
        <div>
  
            <h3>
              File Upload using React!
            </h3>
            <div>
                <input type="file" onChange={this.onFileChange} />
                <button onClick={this.onFileUpload}>
                  Upload!
                </button>
            </div>
          {this.fileData()}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  
  export default Upload;
```

It did not work as expected. I want the put request to put the image which has been uploaded into the S3 bucket.

Comment: There are any number of things that could be wrong. Please provide the error messages/status codes you’re getting.

Comment: I am gettng axios netfwork error

Comment: That's a start! :-) What is the exact error text and error code? Have you put that into Google?